# What to do about "count url clicks" guy

Tags: support, moderation

This has been going on for a few weeks. There is a certain user who is inquiring solely about the topic of links/click counting or user tracking - with only minor variations.

I believe there are accounts which predate these, but I just found:

- **https://stackoverflow.com/users/733618/user733618**

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863105/how-to-count-clicks-on-links-with-php
  - [How to count clicks with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862781/how-to-count-clicks-with-javascript)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858430/how-to-count-clicks-on-specific-links-with-php
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850962/how-to-count-clicks-on-a-get-value-with-php-closed
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851292/how-does-this-site-track-clicks-closed
- **https://stackoverflow.com/users/725446/user725446**

  - [How to display a unique id with $_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849110/how-to-display-a-unique-id-with-get)
  - [How to make an auto-adding MySQL table with unique id increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848721/how-to-make-an-auto-adding-mysql-table-with-unique-id-increment)
  - [How to generate unique id in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792476/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql)
  - [How to change the value which is being counted in this unique hits counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791217/how-to-change-the-value-which-is-being-counted-in-this-unique-hits-counter)
- **https://stackoverflow.com/users/719813/user719813**

  - [How to count and display clicks on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774029/how-to-count-and-display-clicks-on-a-link)
  - [How to track clicks on a php element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773289/how-to-track-clicks-on-a-php-element)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767827/unique-hit-counter-not-working-properly-closed
  - [Help with cookie in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757735/help-with-cookie-in-php)
  - [How to save uuid value for visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757000/how-to-save-uuid-value-for-visitor)
  - [How to save uuid result with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751194/how-to-save-uuid-result-with-cookies-closed)
  - [What form of "log" saving does this site use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750820/what-form-of-log-saving-does-this-site-use)
  - [How to set cookies for uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750658/how-to-set-cookies-for-uuid)

At the very least the accounts should be merged, so downvoting and closevoting would have an effect (automatic ban).

A few of the posts were already deleted, because they looked just like spam links (psncardgenerator.com and xblgenerator.co.cc and freexboxlivecodes.cz.cc...). Not sure if that was really the case here however.

It now seems more like a dedicated troll to me. Cannot believe someone is really that blockheaded. (The questions are just about user counters, where ready-to-use scripts would be available plentiful.)

Comment: Oh wow, I thought just the 3-4 of these that I'd seen were bad enough.  There are nearly three dozen there...

Comment: He's also asked the question on Programmers.SE, where I [closed it outright](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/how-to-count-unique-clicks-on-a-php-value). Nothing spammy about the one on Programmers.SE, it was just low quality (and off-topic).

Comment: Oh, I can believe some users being that stubbornly, arrogantly stupid. :-( Thankfully, it's relatively rare; most people show respect where it is given to them.

Comment: @Mark, he's also [posted it on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13176/how-to-count-unique-clicks-on-a-php-value).

Comment: Looks like there's been some account merging.

Comment: Oooops. Just had to edit one of those questions to remove an upvote *of mine*.

Comment: +1 awesome policemanship! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have (again) merged [user719813](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719813/user719813) with his socks. I also closed several of his questions as duplicates, which leaves him with 7 open, 17 closed, 2 with accepted answers, and 2 deleted.

Given that he's already received two short-term suspensions, and all that they accomplished was to get him to create (even more) socks, I'm hoping that he crosses the "too many lousy questions" line in the very near future.

Mario, thanks for letting us know about this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time with managing this!

Comment: More like userMillipede, amiright?

Comment: @Dori he is totally banned at the moment from asking any more questions by all our metrics.

Comment: Looks like he may have made another. [How to count clicks on a unique link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904853/how-to-count-clicks-on-a-unique-link) is pretty much the same, but mentions that it is for a referral system, which I didn't see on any of the others. This question is the first for [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/740816/user740816), who just joined today.

Comment: @waffles - I thought this guy's IP would be blocked—any reason it isn't/wasn't?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw, thanks for the heads up; I've merged this one in with the others and closed the question as a dupe.